# Dynamically increment width of css element in a for loop

Tags: php, css

EDIT: i found out, itsin my other answer below.

I want to present a graph in php and can create the columns, but when i try to increment the percentage to correspond with the css width of the .inner class it wont increment for each element in he array. How can I increment the width for each element in the array?

```
$percentage = array(0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8);

for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){

echo "<div class='outter'>
<div class='inner'>"; echo $percentage[$i]; echo "
</div>
</div>";

echo "<style type='text/css'>";
echo ".outter{height:25px;width:500%;border-right:solid 1px #000;}";
echo ".inner{height:25px;width:";echo $percentage[i]; echo "%;border-right:solid 1px #000;background-color:#02abff;}";
echo "</style>";

}
```

i can do it in html and css but i want to do it php. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have noticed, but the actual values you have there are `0.X%`, and this is not exactly a valid width. You might want to multiply that value by 10 (or by 100) to get to 2% (or 20%).

```
$percentage = array(0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8);

foreach ($percentage as $key => $val) {
    echo "<div class='outter'>
        <div class='inner'>";
    echo $val;
    echo "</div>
        </div>";

    echo "<style type='text/css'>";
    echo ".outter{height:25px;width:500%;border-right:solid 1px #000;}";
    echo ".inner{height:25px;width:";
    echo $val * 10;
    echo "%;border-right:solid 1px #000;background-color:#02abff;}";
    echo "</style>";
}
```

I also changed the `for` loop that you had there to [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop, which makes more sense when [working with arrays](http://php.net/array).

Comment: yes i tried with all kinds of values, but all columns gets the same width. Im not sure which element, but all gets the same, how ever they have different values inside the div tag. So all columns represent the correct value, but not the correct width in the css.

Answer (score 0):

I found out. I had to put the styling inside the html tag:

```
foreach($percentage as $percent){

echo "<div class='outter' style='height:25px;width:500%;border-right:solid 1px #000;'>
<div class='inner' style='height:25px;width:"; echo $percent; echo "%;border-right:solid 1px #000;background-color:#02abff;'>"; echo $percent; echo "
</div>
</div>";
}
```